# NHibernate programmatically mapping

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I want to create a custom mapping standard so I don't have to create the map.cs file for all new classes in the project.

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Usually I'd have this:

```
public class PersonMap : ClassMapping<Person>
{
    public PersonMap()
    {
        Table("Person");

        Id(p => p.PersonID, map => 
        {
            map.Column("PersonID");
            map.Generator(Generators.Identity);
        });

        Property(p => p.Name, map => map.Column("Name"));
    }
}
```

I'd like to dynamically create these mappings based on some standards using reflection.

```
public class GenericDAL<T> where T : class, new()
{
    public GenericDAL() 
    {
        Configuration hConfig = new Configuration();
        hConfig.DatabaseIntegration(c =>
        {
            c.ConnectionStringName = "myConnectionStringName";
            c.Dialect<MsSql2012Dialect>();
        });

        ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
        //Dynamic Mapping here

        ISessionFactory _sessionFactory = hConfig.BuildSessionFactory();
    }
}
```

I don't know how I can create a new `ClassMapping` from my `T`, how can I do this?

Comment: I actually wrote such a layer for NHibernate about a year ago.  Its not online, but I can make it available if you would find it useful.  Basically, you need to generate a new assembly using the Emit functions to emit the correct IL.  Then load the newly generated assembly into NHibernate.

Comment: Better yet, you should consider using the Mapping Attributes library for NHibernate that is available so you don't have to write your own solution or FluentNHibernate mappings http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhcontrib/files/NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes/

Comment: @SteveLillis You pointed me to the right direction, I wasn't even sure how to do that. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@SteveLillis already answered the question in the comments that there are already solutions for this.

Both MappingByCode in NHibernate (see below) and [FluentNHibernate](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Auto-mapping) support automapping with conventions and overrides.

**Links for Mapping By Code copied from original Answer which is not available anymore**

1. [First impressions](http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/01/nhibernates-mapping-by-code-first.html)
2. [Naming convention resembling Fluent](http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/01/mapping-by-code-naming-convention.html)
3. [Property](http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/01/mapping-by-code-property.html)
4. [Component](http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/01/mapping-by-code-component-and-odd-cases.html)
5. [ManyToOne](http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/01/mapping-by-code-manytoone.html)
6. [inheritance](http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/01/mapping-by-code-inheritance.html)
7. [dynamic component](http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/01/mapping-by-code-dynamic-component.html)
8. [Set and Bag](http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/01/mapping-by-code-set-and-bag.html)
9. [OneToMany and other collection-based relation types](http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/01/mapping-by-code-onetomany-and-other.html)
10. [concurrency](http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/01/mapping-by-code-concurrency.html)
11. [OneToOne](http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/01/mapping-by-code-onetoone.html)
12. [Join](http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/01/mapping-by-code-join.html)
13. [Any](http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/02/mapping-by-code-any.html)
14. [List, Array, IdBag](http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/02/mapping-by-code-list-array-idbag.html)
15. [Map](http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/02/mapping-by-code-map.html)
16. [Id, NaturalId](http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/02/mapping-by-code-id-naturalid.html)
17. [composite identifiers](http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/02/mapping-by-code-composite-identifiers.html)
18. [entity-level mappings](http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/02/mapping-by-code-entity-level-mappings.html)
19. [**the summary**](http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/02/nhibernates-mapping-by-code-summary.html)

Comment: Broken links (1st and 2nd)

Comment: @AndreSoares fixed through inlining one of the links.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing and I found a great documentation on [NHibernate official website](http://nhibernate.info/doc/index.html).

[Here](http://nhibernate.info/doc/howto/mapping/a-fully-working-skeleton-for-sexy-loquacious-nh.html) we have all the links to "fabiomaulo.blogspot" website, there you will find what are you looking for, WITHOUT FluentNHibernate.

Good Luck